# Re-factoring Data After Object.assign

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-structure some data that has been generated using `Object.assign` before saving it as a document in our MongoDB collection. The data looks like this:

```
{ 
  _id: 6d3h7b0bd3e011e73f6ba332,
  updatedAt: 2019-07-02T18:48:12.116Z,
  sqlValues: 'yty',
  data:
   { direction: 'ltr',
     in: { clients: [Object] },
     out: { clients: [Object] } 
   } 
}
```

What I want to do is have the properties within the `data`object appear on the root of the document, like so:

```
{ 
  _id: 6d3h7b0bd3e011e73f6ba332,
  updatedAt: 2019-07-02T18:48:12.116Z,
  sqlValues: 'yty',
  direction: 'ltr',
  in: { clients: [Object] },
  out: { clients: [Object] } 
}
```

How can I accomplish that in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the properties of `data` to the root using the [spread operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

To then remove the `data` property that's already there, use [rest syntax with an object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

```js
const obj = { _id: "6d3h7b0bd3e011e73f6ba332", updatedAt: "2019-07-02T18:48:12.116Z", sqlValues: 'yty', data: { direction: 'ltr', in: {}, out: {} } }; 

let {data, ...result } = {...obj, ...obj.data};
console.log( result );
```

Comment: This is an elegant and effective solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data property alone from the object and assign it to a temporary variable. Then delete that property from the object. Finally get the expected object by spreading the initial object and the temporary variable together.

```js
const ob = {
  _id: '6d3h7b0bd3e011e73f6ba332',
  updatedAt: '2019-07-02T18:48:12.116Z',
  sqlValues: 'yty',
  data: {
    direction: 'ltr',
    in: {
      clients: [Object]
    },
    out: {
      clients: [Object]
    }
  }
};

const data = ob.data;
delete ob.data;

const result = {
  ...ob,
  ...data
};

console.log(result);
```